# Wont scroll on click

Tags: javascript

I want to make it that i scroll towards the section that i click on in my navbar but for some reason the window wont scroll when i click and i get no errors can someone help me, want to accomplish this in vanilla js.

```
(function() {
            var scrollLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll');
            for( var i = 0; i < scrollLinks.length; i++){
                scrollLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    this_ = this;
                    var position = this_.getAttribute("href");

                    scrollIt(position);
                })
            }

            function scrollIt(position){
                console.log(document.querySelector(position).offsetTop)
                window.scrollTo({
                    top: document.querySelector(position).offsetTop,
                    left: 0,
                    behavior: 'smooth',
                });
            }


        })();
```

Comment: Just so you know, you really should avoid naming your variable `location` as it is part of the browser global API; e.g., `window.location`

Comment: changed it to position but it doesn't work still

Comment: When are you loading the script? You should load it at the end of the file. It's quite possible that you're loading it too early, before the DOM has been created, so the script wont find any `.scroll` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the `href` attribute has a leading `#` character because you are passing this directly to the `.querySelector()` method and also your sections need to have matching `id`s. Check this out (your JavaScript code is not changed at all, I only added valid HTML to it):

```js
(function() {
            var scrollLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll');
            for( var i = 0; i < scrollLinks.length; i++){
                scrollLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    this_ = this;
                    var location = this_.getAttribute("href");

                    scrollIt(location);
                })
            }

            function scrollIt(location){
                console.log(document.querySelector(location).offsetTop)
                window.scrollTo({
                    top: document.querySelector(location).offsetTop,
                    left: 0,
                    behavior: 'smooth',
                });
            }


        })();
```

```css
html, body {

  height: 10000px;
}
#s1 {
  margin-top: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a class="scroll" href="#s1">s1</a>
</nav>
<section id="s1">Section 1</section>
```

Comment: I have not share my full html here but i actually have that and is wont work

Comment: Then maybe it's a good idea to share it. It's clearly something wrong with your HTML because as you can see in my answer, your JS works as expected.